# Evernote findNotes by sourceURL

Tags: evernote

I'm trying to search notes by the attribute sourceURL but it seems API is stripping away the protocol and the result is no results. Here is the code

```
    var notesTransport = new Thrift.Transport(
            Eventnote.Auth.oauth.getParameter(Eventnote.Auth.note_store_url_param));

    var notesProtocol = new Thrift.Protocol(notesTransport);
    var noteStore = new NoteStoreClient(notesProtocol, notesProtocol);
    if (!noteStore) {
      Eventnote.Logger.error("[EVERDU] Connection failure during getting note store");
      return;
    }

    var filter = new NoteFilter();
    filter.words = "sourceURL:" + url + "*";
    try {
      var results = noteStore.findNotes(Eventnote.Auth.get_auth_token(), filter,
        0, 100);
      ...
```

The reasults objects looks like this

```
{
   "startIndex":0,
   "totalNotes":0,
   "notes":[

   ],
   "stoppedWords":null,
   "searchedWords":[
      "//github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab*"
   ],
   "updateCount":18461
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that counts as a bug on Evernote's end or not, butyou can add double quotes around your url to make it work.

```
filter.words = "sourceURL:\"" + url + "*\"";
```